# How to calculate the total duration of specific event in pyspark dataframe?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Suppose we have a CSV file below and have already defined the schema/DataFrame (test_data) in pyspark. And, how to use spark SQL(PySpark) to get the total duration (in mins) of all the driving events?

For the below tables, the total duration should be: (`6:12 - 5:12`) + (`8:12 - 7:12`) = 2 hours = 120 mins.

Below are some of my init code: (Please correct me if I should not use the below code)

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("test_data")
df2 = spark.sql("SELECT * from test_data")
```

|  | TimeDetails | Event | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3/1/18 5:12 | Driving | start |
| 2 | 3/1/18 6:12 | Driving | end |
| 3 | 3/1/18 7:12 | Driving | start |
| 4 | 3/1/18 8:12 | Driving | end |
| 5 | 3/1/18 9:12 | Biking | start |
| 6 | 3/1/18 10:12 | Biking | end |
| 7 | 3/1/18 11:12 | Biking | start |
| 8 | 3/1/18 0:12 | Biking | end |
| …. |  |  |  |

Can someone please provide me with some code in PySpark SQL?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to identify each driving session then group by and subtract the `end - start` timestamp to find the duration of each session. And finally, sum all the durations to get total driving.

- Filtering the dataframe on event is `driving` and creating `session_id` column using cumulative conditional sum:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

# convert TimeDetails column into timestamp if it's not already done
df = df.withColumn("TimeDetails", F.to_timestamp("TimeDetails", "d/M/yy H:mm"))

w = Window.orderBy("TimeDetails")

df = df.filter("Event = 'Driving'").withColumn(
    "session_id",
    F.sum(F.when(F.col("Value") == "start", 1).otherwise(0)).over(w)
)

df.show()
#+-------------------+-------+-----+----------+
#|        TimeDetails|  Event|Value|session_id|
#+-------------------+-------+-----+----------+
#|2018-01-03 05:12:00|Driving|start|         1|
#|2018-01-03 06:12:00|Driving|  end|         1|
#|2018-01-03 07:12:00|Driving|start|         2|
#|2018-01-03 08:12:00|Driving|  end|         2|
#+-------------------+-------+-----+----------+
```

- Now group by `session_id` to calculate the session duration and sum:

```
result = df.groupBy("session_id").agg(
    (
      (F.max("TimeDetails").cast("long") - F.min("TimeDetails").cast("long")) / 60
    ).alias("session_duration")
).select(
    F.sum("session_duration").alias("total_drive_duration")
)

result.show()
#+--------------------+
#|total_drive_duration|
#+--------------------+
#|               120.0|
#+--------------------+
```

Comment: one more thing, How can I get the total duration of the date "2018-01-03" instead of all days. thank you

Comment: @Lawrence add the date in the filter `df.filter("Event = 'Driving' AND to_date(TimeDetails) = '2018-01-03'")`